# Help! I'm trapped in a wall!

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've managed to get myself stuck in the geometry of a wall. I can't jump or walk or dodge out it seems. In most other MMO's I've played, **/Stuck**, or **/Unstuck** or some variant thereof can be used to rectify such a situation, however, nothing I can seem to think of is working in GW2.

Tantalizingly, **/stuck** doesn't seem to produce an '**Unknown command**' error - but it also doesn't *do* anything.

Also, I am an idiot with no money and cannot use a waypoint.

Comment: This happened to me just a few minutes ago.  The only thing I could do was use a waypoint.

Comment: This happened to me once and I didn't think to use a waypoint. I was able to get out by auto-running and mashing the spacebar for a few minutes. YMMV.

Comment: You know who else is stuck in a wall: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarkali

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be playing a mesmer, would you?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Engineer!

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Ah, then my mesmer-specific tricks for using your teleportation skills to unstuck yourself are probably not relevant.

Comment: I've successfully used '/stuck' before - I'd got stuck in a wall of an inn and it teleported me outside. Not sure why it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: @ravendreamer of course they are relevant! To somebody else, if not to me.

Comment: Well, it's not complicated. If you have a staff, use 2. If you have it unlocked, use the "blink" utility.

Comment: Engineer, I'd be trying the rocket jump ability.

Comment: /stuck is finicky. It only seems to work if your collision geometry is overlapping with environmental collision geometry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, you have to use a waypoint. If you don't have the money to, open the pvp interface and teleport to the heart of the mists - and from there, enter the portal to Lion's Arch.

Comment: Even if you don't have enough money to pay the waypoint cost, you can still use them.

Comment: Just to expand on what Brant said, if you dont have enough money to use a waypoint, then either the money will be taken from your bank or, if you dont have any in the bank, the closest waypoint to you will be free to use.

Comment: This is the case when you're dead. It is not true if you are still alive but stuck, AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

Once I got stuck in a tree so I used a few spare skill points to unlock and try a couple different [teleport](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Teleport) skills, eventually as a guardian I was able to use Judge's Intervention on a nearby bird and got out of the tree.